# Making an Excel histogram with single bin size and whole number vertical axes

Tags: excel, histogram

I'm at a loss as to how to make a simple histogram in Excel. I have the following range of values that I want to make into a histogram with a bin size of 1, showing numbers 1 through 58 on the horizontal axis, and a vertical axis with only whole numbers 0 through 5. Except this is what I keep ending up with:

```
24 37 02 16 24 34 34 32 34 39
26 38 12 58 57 55 50 38 35 26
52 50 45 25 14 26 32 32 31 33
34 20 19 17 22 54 53 50 40 02
08 30 06 28 22
```

[Histogram link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uOIHh.png)

I have no idea why the horizontal bins can't show a single number to represent a size of one or why I can't get rid of the superfluous vertical grids. The horizontal axis settings are: Bin width 1.0 [why the decimal place?], Number of bins 56, Overflow bin 76.0, Underflow bin -13.0, Number category General, Format code General. Vertical axis settings are: Axis bounds minimum 0.0, maximum 5.0, Display units none, Number category Number, Decimal places 0, Format code 0.

Comment: hello , check this link :https://www.statisticshowto.com/probability-and-statistics/excel-statistics/histogram-in-excel/#:~:text=Step%201%3A%20Enter%20your%20data,then%20click%20a%20histogram%20icon.

Comment: I don't see how that solves my problem if I'm using the latest version of Excel (like 2016) and I can't add a Bin column